# Загрузка фотографии на сервер не работает

Tags: php, upload

Делаю загрузку фотографии на сервер, клиент отправляет фото, а сервер не принимает. Вернее принимает, потому что проверка `isFileExists` или на `is_uploaded_file` проходит, в таблицу добавляется запись, скорее всего не работает перемещение из временного хранилища в папку (функция `move_uploaded_file`). Папка `imgs789` находится на том же уровне, что и скрипт. А вот и он кстати

```
<?php
if (file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) || is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
$f = '/imgs789';
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$dbname = 'f36545_db';
$dbuser = 'f36545_dbuser';
$dbpass = 'k9TlP>uBiEDsIHie';
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$link -> set_charset("utf8");
$link -> query("INSERT INTO `photo_hotel` (`_id`) VALUES (NULL)") or die(mysqli_error($link));
$pid = $link -> insert_id;
$url = $imgf.$pid.".img";
$to = $f."/".$pid.".png";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $to);
}
else{
echo 'file not uploaded';
}
?>
```

В таблицу добавляется пустая запись, просто решил обзывать фотки порядковым числом

Comment: У вас в корневой директории сервера что-ли скрипт лежит? Вы указываете абсолютный путь в переменной $f.

Comment: @Dmitry OnGamer, так и знал что что-то с путем, потому что как-то было что сам скрипт перемещается)

Comment: @Dmitry OnGamer, судя из этой статьи http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/paths мне нужно перед слешем поставь точку? :)

Comment: @Dmitry OnGamer, стоп, я видимо не понял. Да, лежит в корне

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так 
`$f = __DIR__ . '/imgs789';` 
и убедитесь что есть права на запись.

Comment: Огроменное спасибо!